# Join tables in eclipselink (jpa)

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, vaadin, jpql

I'm trying to convert a simple sql statement to jpql but vainly. I have an entity "Banque" that has many "Compte" and i'm trying to get all the "Compte" for a specific "Banque" using id_Banque.

This is the sql statement :

```
SELECT COMPTE.* FROM COMPTE INNER JOIN BANQUE ON COMPTE.ID_BANQUE=BANQUE.ID_BANQUE;
```

============================**Entity Banque**=========================

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANQUE")
public class Banque implements Serializable{
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="banque_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="banque_seq_gen", sequenceName="BANQUE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id_banque;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Banque")
    private Set<Compte> comptes;

public Banque(){

    }
}
```

============================**Entity Compte**=========================

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COMPTE")
public class Compte implements Serializable{

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="compte_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="compte_seq_gen", sequenceName="COMPTE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id_compte;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_BANQUE")
    private Banque Banque;

    public Compte(){

    }
}
```

And the following method help me to get all the comptes (Entity compte) associated to a specific Banque (from id_banque) :

```
public Set<Compte> getComptesFromIdBanque(Long id_banque){
    EntityManager em=new JPAContainerFactory().createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit("addressbook");
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Compte c INNER JOIN c.Banque b WHERE b.id_banque = :id_banque");

    query.setParameter("id_banque", id_banque);
    Set<Compte> comptes = new HashSet<>(query.getResultList());
    return comptes;
}
```

This is an illustration of the two tables and what i'd like to have :

[image]

Then a display this list of comptes in a ComboBox :

```
compteCombo.addItems(saut.getComptesFromIdBanque(banque.getId_banque()));
compteCombo.setItemCaptionPropertyId("numero");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't show any item in the comboBox.

I hope i will find a pertinent answer as i searched for this in vain. It'll help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'm confused by your simple SQL statement. Couldn't you just `SELECT * FROM COMPTE WHERE ID_BANQUE=N`?

Comment: Similarly, your JPQL looks fine to me, but you could simplify it: `SELECT c FROM Compte c WHERE c.banque.id_banque = :id_banque`. JPA can traverse the object graph for you in some cases like this one.

Comment: You mention that "this doesn't show any item in the comboBox". You should confirm that your query is returning results before you involve more components, such as the UI. Put some log statements in `getComptesFromIdBanque` to confirm your query results.

Comment: If you're using Netbeans, you can test your JPQL queries in the [JPQL query editor](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/test_jpql_with_netbeans_ide).

Comment: Lastly, if you haven't already, you should read the entire [JPQL tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html). It's not long and it is a good introduction, and the description of relationship traversal is important.

Comment: Well, your answers are organized and helpful. The method works fine and it returns the exact result, however the problem is when i bind the result to the ComboBox. 

Now i use the "BeanItemContainer" and it works fine. 

Thanks again for your answer, i believe it is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your JPA query seems fine to me (although as @Davids mentioned it could be simplified to `SELECT c FROM Compte c WHERE c.banque.id_banque = :id_banque`).

My guess is your [ComboBox caption](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selection.html#components.selection.captions) is not set up properly to show anything.

First, write a test to make sure your JPA function returns the right data. Then play around with the `setItemCaptionMode` of `ComboBox` to get the right setting. Assuming your `Compete` class has a `getNumero()` method, you can set up your Combobox like this:

```
compteCombo = new ComboBox( "Caption", saut.getComptesFromIdBanque(banque.getId_banque()) );
compteCombo.setItemCaptionMode( ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY );
compteCombo.setItemCaptionPropertyId( "numero" );
```